# While fetching data from API and logging it getting this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at App.js:24:1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

While fetching data from API and logging it getting this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON  at App.js:24:1"

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import CurrentWeather from "./component/current-weather/current-weather";
import { WEATHER_API_KEY, WEATHER_API_URL } from "./component/search/api";
import Search from "./component/search/search";

function App() {
    const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState(null);
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);

    const handleOnSearchChange = (searchData) => {
        const [lat, lon] = searchData.value.split(" ");

        const currentWeatherFetch = fetch(
            `${WEATHER_API_URL}/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`
        );

        const forecastFetch = fetch(
            `${WEATHER_API_URL}/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon={${lon}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`
        );

        Promise.all([currentWeatherFetch, forecastFetch])
            .then(async (response) => {
                const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
                const forcastResponse = await response[1].json();

                setCurrentWeather({
                    city: searchData.label,
                    ...weatherResponse,
                });
                setForecast({ city: searchData.label, ...forcastResponse });
            })
            .catch(console.log);
    };
    console.log(currentWeather);
    console.log(forecast);
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Search onSearchChange={handleOnSearchChange} />
            <CurrentWeather />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**api.js**

```
export const geoApiOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_GEODB_API_KEY,
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
};

export const GEO_API_URL = "https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo";

export const WEATHER_API_URL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";

export const WEATHER_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
```

I manually gave the api link in browser and got this result
`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=-27.47&lon=153.12&appid=<API_KEY>`

```
{"coord":{"lon":153.12,"lat":-27.47},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":296.36,"feels_like":296.75,"temp_min":295.22,"temp_max":297.15,"pressure":1016,"humidity":77},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":120},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1673616299,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9485,"country":"AU","sunrise":1673550242,"sunset":1673599638},"timezone":36000,"id":2176264,"name":"Belmont","cod":200}
```

While getting response instead of response getting error.
Not sure what i did wrong here.

While getting response instead of response getting error.

From comment got suggestion how to get the whole response,
Here what i got,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

There isn't any error related anything

Comment: Look at the error, you are not returning a valid JSON data structure but rather HTML, or at least the start of an HTML doc declaration .

Comment: Your call is returning back a html page, This can happen when the API returns the error in html format. For example "Permission denied" page. Try to open that link directly in the browser and see what it says. I think that you can also open the response of that API call and see the page there

Comment: I gave the api link in browser got the result, have updated in the description

Comment: and that's what i am asking did i do something wrong while getting the response of the api?

Comment: You can probably read the problem if you read the HTML contents of the page returned. `const weatherResponseText = await response[0].text()` then `console.log(weatherResponseText)` and finally `const weatherResponse = JSON.parse(weatherResponseText)`. The same applies for `forcastResponse`. Read the contents of the HTML returned, does it say anything useful? Alternatively you could wrap the `JSON.parse()` with a `try`/`catch` and only log the HTML on error.

Comment: I have added it in the description the response[0].text()

there's nothing useful

Comment: I've noticed that `WEATHER_API_URL` is defined without scheme `https://` the variable should be probably be `export const WEATHER_API_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5"`, this is most likely the source of your problems. If you would check the network request (`Ctrl+Shift+I` then go the *network* tab) you would probably see that the request is send to `http://localhost:<some port>/api.openweathermap.org/...`

Comment: for parse, i am getting this,

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at App.js:29:1

Comment: so should i define it with https://?

Comment: @AadilKhatri Yes, without it `fetch()` requests data from the current origin.

Comment: yes it got resolved when i added "https://" Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be here.

```
export const WEATHER_API_URL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
```

It should be -

```
export const WEATHER_API_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
```